# Arrow key navigation in treeview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treeview control in asp.net. I need to navigate through its nodes, using the up and down arrow keys. I cannot find any property for the same. Also, there is no keydown event for treeview. Please help!

Comment: You must have to *learn/use* client programming language - `JavaScript` to handle [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/event.keyCode) and mouse events.

Comment: try the solution from the below link http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=404110

Comment: Also, please help me with selecting a particular node by default. whenever I execute the following: treeViewReportList.SelectedNode = treeViewReportList.Nodes[0];
It give an error saying that SelectedNode is a read only property. Is there any method to select a node if the index is given?

Answer (score 5):

asp.net is a **server-side** technology. Keydown events happen **client-side**. You don't want to post to the server every time the user presses a key, so you should use some client-side technology such as javascript (plain or using the jQuery library) to handle the browser's keydown event. Take a look at this [jQuery example](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would also appreciate it if you could give me an example of how I can use javascript code in an asp.net page for handling key down.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to implement that through Javascript, using a library like jQuery makes that a lot easier, i.e.

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: could you please tell me where exactly to put this code?

Comment: on (oopps in) the head

Answer (score 0):

a keydown event is a client-side action, u can catch a keydown even like this :

example

onKeyDown="alert('cheese');"

Comment: navigating in a treeview is more complicated , u have to write a javascript which gets triggered by the keydown event and there u have to catch which arrowkey was pressed, and depending on that , execute ur desired action